# replacing a corrupted dll in a solution of 300 projects?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

My VS2013 solution has 300 projects and references of every project contains a dll, somehow it is corrupted, I would like to replace it with correct one. How can I do it for all 300 projects at once?

Comment: You'll probably have to use some tool to go through your project files and do a search and replace text operation - like this https://findandreplace.codeplex.com/ one

Comment: And then once you've solved your reference problem tell yourself not to have that many projects in one solution...

Comment: Well, nothing that Edit > Find and Replace > Replace in Files won't let you do.  Practice, have a good backup.